# How much DRAM does u-boot occupy?

Tags: memory, embedded-linux, ram, u-boot

I want to perform some operation(load a small firmware) while i am in u-boot.
Does someone know how much DRAM does u-boot occupy in the beginning and end of DRAM,
so that i can load my firmware in the unoccupied area of DRAM which is not occupied by u-boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U-Boot is configurable, so the answer depends on your specific build. 
 The commands and features configured into U-Boot will determine its actual size.  Typically U-Boot is built to reside/execute in the upper portion of main memory, and the remainder of low memory is available for whatever.

In your board's config file, the definition for `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE` sets the start address of U-Boot.  (Older versions of U-Boot had a different method of specifying this start address symbol.)

Examine the generated `System.map` file (in the same directory as the `u-boot.bin` executable) for the addresses that the linker has assigned to each entry point.

In your board's config file, there's also something like:

```
#define CONFIG_SYS_SDRAM_BASE       ATMEL_BASE_CS6
#define CONFIG_SYS_SDRAM_SIZE       0x08000000
```

to define the physical address range of main memory.

U-Boot will start its stack at the end of SDRAM, or BASE+SIZE.
So the region between `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE`+(size of u-boot.bin) and the end of SDRAM is the available stack area.

U-Boot will also use memory below `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE` for its `malloc()` pool.  The size of that region is defined by `CONFIG_SYS_MALLOC_LEN`.

So the memory between `CONFIG_SYS_SDRAM_BASE` and
`CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE`-`CONFIG_SYS_MALLOC_LEN` should be available.

**ADDENDUM**

The above comments apply to a U-Boot that is loaded and executed in main memory (i.e. DRAM).
Some systems execute U-Boot out of ROM or NOR Flash, and then U-Boot will relocate itself to RAM.  Some (old?) documentation is [here](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/DebuggingUBoot#Section_10.1.1.).

Comment: Thanks sawdust. In my setup, I have 
#define CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE    0xFF600000
which is NOR's address where the u-boot is residing.
The starting address of RAM is 
#define CONFIG_SYS_DDR_BASE             0x00000000
The size of my RAM is 
#define CONFIG_SYS_DDR_SIZE             256.
Could you kindly help me in calculating the stack area as you have mentioned above?
(U-Boot will start its stack at the end of SDRAM, or BASE+SIZE. So the region between CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE+(size of u-boot.bin) and the end of SDRAM is the available stack area)

Comment: *"NOR's address where the u-boot is residing"* - Is this just for storage, or execution-in-place?  RAM starting at 0x0 and a size of only 256 does not seem correct.  What SoC is on your board?

Comment: It is execution-in-place. Its an embedded system with small ram. Soc is mpc8308

Comment: sawdust where can i get all the above imformation you have shared? I would like to read and learn about it.

Comment: Most of what I've described came from inspecting the code.  Please note the addendum to answer.  Does your board have 256 bytes or 256 **MB** of RAM?  Sorry, but I'm not familiar with configuring U-Boot to execute out of NOR or ROM.

Comment: Board has 256 MB of RAM
#define CONFIG_SYS_DDR_SIZE 256 /* MB */